# How to store a private key in token/smart card using keygen tag in Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, private-key, pki, key-pair

I need to specify the location of private key storage to smart cards/tokens using the keygen tag.
Using Mozilla Firefox, when a form containing the keygen tag is submitted and any cryptographic hardware device is plugged in, the browser prompts a combo box where i can choose which storage device i want to put my private key in.
Yet, when using Google Chrome, it doesnt prompt the combo box and always store the private key in disk!
Anyone already face the same problem? Any alternative solution?

Thx!